# How can I exclude code coverage for certain tests

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage

I am collecting code coverage data for my PHP unit tests; some are unit tests and some are integration tests checking that everything (classes and config) is wired up correctly.

I only wish to collect code coverage information while running the unit tests, as it is the unit tests that should be shown to cover all lines in the target class(es) (ideally using `@covers` annotations). The integration tests should not be shown to cover anything at all, but the default position of phpunit seems to be that if it doesn't have any `@covers` annotation, then it should be covering every line of code that is directly or indirectly called by each test method.

Note that using a `<whitelist>` in the `phpunit.xml` won't help me because some files may be touched by both sets of tests - and I want to record code coverage originating from one while excluding the other.

I've thought of several ways that this may be possible, but none of them seem 'clean' to me:

- Adding a false `@covers` declaration to the test class' docblock

  > This works, but as stated, adding a dummy `@covers` like: `/** @covers \stdClass */` feels so, so dirty.
- <strike>Adding `codeCoverageIgnoreStart`/`End` annotations around the body of each test method (I do not know if this works)</strike>

  > Similarly to below, this only seems to exclude the lines of code wrapped, not any lines of code called thereupon
- <strike>Adding `codeCoverageIgnore` annotation to the test class (I suspect that this will not work, due to just excluding the code in the class from coverage collection, but resuming collection for any dependant code)</strike>

  > Tested this, as suspected this just has the semantics that no lines within the test class should be considered covered
- Separating them into separate suites for which code coverage is collected for one and not the other. (Ideally all tests should be executed in one run)

Is there a cleaner way of doing this than any of the above possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest feeling method I've found so far is a variation of the first approach outlined above: to refer the class to itself in the `@covers` annotation:

```
<?php

namespace FooTestSuite;

/** @covers \FooTestSuite\BarTest */
class BarTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    /* ... */

}
```